# looping through sheets in a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me how to get the following code to run on sheets 5-45?
I currently have a button created on each worksheet to do what the code below 
tells it to do, but I would like to make ONE button in sheet 50 to have the code
below run on every sheet from 5-45. (i'm not very good at javascript...just looking for some help)

```
// To import data from the the last sheet and populate it 
// into rows D and E of the current worksheet

function SearchCols() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                               
var expen = ss.getSheetByName("MRS summary")                                                  
var sheet1 = expen.getRange("A13:A210").getValues();                                          

var searchCol1 = expen.getRange ('B13:B210').getValues();                                     
var searchCol2 = expen.getRange ('A13:A210').getValues();                                     
var searchCol3 = expen.getRange('C13:C210').getValues();                                      
var searchCol4 = expen.getRange('D13:D210').getValues();                                         

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                                              
var searchCol = sss.getRange('A13:A210').getValues();                                         
var searchVal = sss.getRange('B4').getValue();                                                
var col1 = sss.getActiveSheet();                                                              
var col2 = sss.getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)                                                           
  for (var j = 0, len2 = searchCol1.length; j < len2; j++)                                      
  {
    if (searchCol2[j][0] == searchVal && searchCol1[j][0] == searchCol[i]
[0])                   
    { 
      col1.getRange(i + 13, 4).setValue(searchCol3[j][0])                                        
      col2.getRange(i + 13, 5).setValue(searchCol4[j][0])                                        
    }
}
}
```

I've tried to add the outer loop (for (var g in allsheets)) to go through every sheet, but it still only works on the ACTIVE sheet. But I can see in the log file (using Logger.log(g);) that it IS looping thorugh all values of g, meaning the sheets) Where did I go wrong? See below:

```
function SearchCols() 
{
  var ssss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allsheets = ssss.getSheets();
  for (var g in allsheets)
     {
       Logger.log(g);
       var sheet = allsheets[g]                                              
       var expen = ssss.getSheetByName("MRS summary")                                                  
       var sheet1 = expen.getRange("A13:A210").getValues();                                          

       var searchCol1 = expen.getRange ('B13:B210').getValues();                                     
       var searchCol2 = expen.getRange ('A13:A210').getValues();                                     
       var searchCol3 = expen.getRange ('C13:C210').getValues();                                      
       var searchCol4 = expen.getRange ('D13:D210').getValues();                                         

       var searchCol = ssss.getRange('A13:A210').getValues();                                         
       var searchVal = ssss.getRange('B4').getValue();                                                
       var col1 = ssss.getActiveSheet();                                                              

       for (var i = 0, len = searchCol2.length; i < len; i++)                                                           
       for (var j = 0, len2 = searchCol1.length; j < len2; j++)                                      
       {
         if (searchCol2[j][0] == searchVal && searchCol1[j][0] == 
             searchCol[i][0])                   
         { 
           col1.getRange(i + 13, 4).setValue(searchCol3[j][0])                                        
           col1.getRange(i + 13, 5).setValue(searchCol4[j][0])                                        
         }
       }
     } 
}
```

Comment: I've edited the 2nd code a few times.....so it's looping through the sheets (I currently have 4 sheets and the logger file shows 0,1,2,3, so I know the code is hitting all sheets, but it only runs the code that prints the data for the CURRENT sheet...i need it to run on all sheets. (actually, I only want it to run on sheets 1, 2 and 3). Any thoughts?

Comment: PS. this code is supposed to compare columns from the LAST sheet to a cell AND a column in sheets 4-45. when both of those conditions are met, it then pastes rows from the last sheet to sheets 4-45. and right now, i have this working with a button on every worksheet. but i need to get rid of the button on each worksheet and only use ONE button in the last worksheet to do all of this work. thats why i need this code to loop through sheets 4-45. thx again.

Comment: I can actually see the cells on the ACTIVE worksheet getting pasted over  and over for the # of spreadsheets that exist. so I know that the loop to count the number of sheets is working, because when i run the script, the cells that should get populated with data seem to 'beat' or refresh the # of times as the # of sheets that exist. I just need to know how go get the code to move over to the NEXT spreadsheet so the code can repeat on that worksheet and so on.